# How to debug AJAX entity wrapper error?

Tags: forms, entities, database, ajax

I'm writing a module and it's form aspects are fine, including fetching data from my database. I use entity metadata wrapper to fetch the field data from my database. I'm using data from a field collection in entityform submissions. I use a URL/page argument to select the specific entityform submission I'm pulling from.

The issue is when adding ajax functionality to any textfield it gives a 500 error. Doesn't matter what (or anything) I have in the AJAX callback function, it bombs. The error messages don't give me enough info, as far as I can tell, other than it seems to be related to the page argument that specifies the individual entityform ID. BTW, PHP memory is 256 (I mention this as the most common reported cause of a 500 error seems to be low PHP memory - don't think that's my issue).

Here are the error messages:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occured. HTTP Result Code: 500. EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at entityform(): ajax. in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 756 of /home/mysite/mysite.dreamhosters.com/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in investment_lineitems_form() (line 48 of /home/mysite/mysite.dreamhosters.com/sites/all/modules/investment_lineitems/investment_lineitems.module).
```

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form()
 */
 function investment_lineitems_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $itemcounter = 0;

    $entityform = array_pop(arg());   // ****  THIS IS LINE 48 

    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('entityform', $entityform); 


    foreach ($wrapper->field_inv_account_details as $field_collection_wrapper) {
      $field_your_percent_a = $field_collection_wrapper->field_inv_your_percent_split_a->value();
      $itemcounter++;
      if (!empty($field_item_value)){


    $form['edit_your_percent_amount_'.$itemcounter] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
        //'#title' => 'Item Value '.$itemcounter, //Form the field label
        '#size' => 5,
        '#maxlength' => 5,
        '#value'=>$field_your_percent_a,
        '#required' => FALSE, //make this field required 
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_alert_callback',
        ),
        //'#weight' => 5,
           );
               }
    }

  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save Changes'),
    '#weight' => 15,
  );

  return $form;  
}

 /**
 * Callback for 'alert'.    USE THIS FOR TESTING AND DEBUGGING
 *
 * @see ajax_command_alert()
 */
function ajax_alert_callback($form, $form_state) {
  //$commands = array();
  //$commands[] = dsm($form_state['triggering_element']); //ajax_command_alert("Alert requested");
  //return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);

}
```

Note: My callback function shows commented lines - attempts to debug the issue. Even without anything in that function I get the error, so it doesn't even seem to get that far.

Any recommendations or suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Have you used xdebug to step through the code?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I haven't used xdebug, just Devel. I have PHPstorm and will see if I can install xdebug on my Dreamhosters hosting account, and report back.

Comment: You can setup DrupalVM locally with the same settings (probably) and enable xdebug and work locally. From there, you can use PHPStorm to easily drop breakpoints and trigger xdebug. Great way to walk through AJAX debugging, because I don't think much else is effective.

Comment: Yeah, hit a dead end with Dreamhosters account. I don't have sufficient control/rights to install Zend and Xdebug. I have an old early dev version of my site on WAMP/localhost, so I'll use Backup & Migrate to bring it up to speed and see if I can then use xdebug. Wish there was an easier quicker way to identify the issue though...

Comment: So, I'm not getting anywhere trying to install xdebug without having to build a new instance of Drupal and then try to replicate my module for that environment.

In the meantime, if I comment out the line indicated in the error and replace it with a fixed value, like so:

`
$entityform = 68; //array_pop(arg());
`

then the error goes away, so this is something to do with that argument I pass in the URL to use the entityform ID in my wrapper formation. Any ideas why that should be causing the error - when there's an AJAX callback does that argument get lost/corrupted?

Comment: Just use DrupalVM.com. Super simple to setup and has it all.

Comment: The answer to your question is possibly, POSSIBLY, that if you are reading `arg()` from within an AJAX callback, that the path is not what you expect. I bet if you were to log the path, it would be 'system/ajax' which is why that would fail. The AJAX callbacks are processed on their own path and not the current one.

Comment: That would seem to be what's happening, but just "ajaxifying" the field causes this, so there's no code specific to AJAX that I can see to correct/modify to work around this. However, if I hard-code the value (not pulling from URL) then it works. I wonder if there's a place in the module where I can pull the arg and assign it to a variable where it is not effected thereafter by the AJAX callback. On the face of it, it looks like AJAX re-runs my entire form code. I'll experiment with alternate locations for the arg fetching. I didn't know about DrupalVM - I'll check  that out. Thanks Kevin.